# What the query in mongodb for filter, get data on nested array, and pagination based on nested array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo-server

i have a problem here, i need to filter, get data from nested array, and paginate the data based on nested array (child property with array) in the mongodb data

my data is embeded document like this

```
school: [{
    _id: "5d9eb788536e7a17b8032469"
    name: "school one"
    status: true
    class: [{
        name: "class one"
        }, {
        name: "class two"
    }]
}, {
    _id: "5d7b570c135dc32bb40d8943"
    name: "school two"
    Status: true
    class: [{
        name: "class one"
    }, {
        name: "class three"
    }
}]
```

i want to filter by status: true, and class name is "class one" only, and then paginate based on class. the result i need is like this:

```
result: [{
    class: {
        name: "class one"
    }
    school_name: "school one"
    status: true
}, {
    class: {
        name: "class one"
    }
    school_name: "school two"
    status: true
}]
```

what the query in mongoose, if i need filter the data like that and give me result like a in that schema ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('db').aggregate([{
    "$unwind":"$class"
    },{
        "$match":{
            "class.name":"class one"
            }
        },{
            "$group":{
                "_id":null,
                "result":{
                    "$push":"$class"
                    }
                }
            },{
                "$project":{
                    "_id":0
                    }
                }])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query

```
    db.getCollection('db').aggregate(
    { "$addFields": {
        "class": 
          {
              "$filter": {
                      "input": "$class",
                      "as": "sn",
                      "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                          { "$eq": [ "$$sn.name", "class one" ] },
                     ]
              }
          }
       } 

    }}
    )
```